# Joining two tables in two different servers with PHP (Foreach)

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach

[image]

I have two databases in two different servers.

In these two databases, I have two tables with the same name 'orders'. (see the Picture)

There are informations in the orders table in database2 that I need eg column 'import' and 'shipping'.

For joining the two tables i used two foreach loop :

```
<?php
$all=array();

// get 100 Records from 30 000 Records (Database1) because i work with pagination
$ordersFromDB1="SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 0,100"; 

// get all 10 0000 Records for checking (Database2)
$ordersFromDB2="SELECT * FROM orders"; 

foreach ($ordersFromDB1 as $order1) {  //100 times

    foreach ($ordersFromDB2 as $order2) {  //10 000 times


        if ($order1['ID_order']==$order2['ID_order']) {

           //put column "import" from order2 in order1
           $order1['import']=$order2['import'];

           // put column "shipping" from order2 in order1
           $order1['shipping']=$order2['shipping'];

         }
   }

   $all[]=$order1;
}
//foreach loop will be execute 100 * 10 000 = 1 000 000 times

// $all stoke the two orders table (orders1,orders2) in one array
```

This code work fine but if you see the loop foreach will be execute 100 * 10 000 = 1 000 000 times i think that is not a good idea.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: How often do you need the query to be ran?

Comment: I think databases use [sort-merge join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join) by utilizing the index. You can probably emulate it if you add an `ORDER BY` in your select. Of course the best solution is to migrate one of your databases on the same server as the other one but I'm assuming that's not an option here.

Comment: @Dammeul The two queries are executed once

Comment: @apokryfos  Yes I can not because the first database is used from another application for this reason I can not change the structure of the database

Comment: Look at sort-merge join , that should be 10000 + 100 operations instead of 10000 * 100 so probably more acceptable.

Comment: You can use sub query. Like order IDs of first query in where clause of second query. Iterate on only matched records.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have your both order arrays in format:

```
$orders1 = array('order_id' => order)
$orders2 = array('order_id' => order)
```

You can do something like this:

```
foreach ($orders2 as $id => $order2) {
    if (array_key_exists($id, $orders1)) {
        $orders1[$id]['import'] = $order2['import'];
    }
}
```

This should take `linear` time with respect to number of order you have.

**EDIT:**
Conversion of the returned DB rows to the proposed format also takes linear time so still much more efficient than your initial solution.